# Why does the first IF statement not working in this recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, date, recursion, search

For some unknown reason the below code doesn't give true in spite Year being equal to current_year and both are of type int! Any thoughts? I am not sure what is the issue

```
def binary_search_year(searchList, Year):
    searchList.sort()
    currentMiddle = len(searchList) // 2
    current_year = searchList[currentMiddle].year
    

    if current_year == Year:
        return True

    elif Year < current_year:
        binary_search_year(searchList[:currentMiddle], Year) 
        
    else:
        try:
            binary_search_year(searchList[currentMiddle + 1:], Year)
        except IndexError:
            return False
    return False
```

Comment: You need to `return` the result from the recursive calls. Currently you make recursive calls and ignore the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

The first `if` **does** execute `return True` when the value is equal, but the problem is that the caller doesn't capture this return value and just ignores it.

The problem is not in that `if`, but in how you deal with the function call that returns `True`.

So change:

```
binary_search_year(searchList[:currentMiddle], Year)
```

to:

```
return binary_search_year(searchList[:currentMiddle], Year)
```

And similarly:

```
binary_search_year(searchList[currentMiddle + 1:], Year)
```

should be:

```
return binary_search_year(searchList[currentMiddle + 1:], Year)
```

Some other remarks:

- It is inefficient to `sort` the list, and certainly to sort each slice **again** in the recursive calls! If your list is not sorted, it makes no sense to perform a binary search to begin with. In that case just walk over the list from left to right (without sorting).
- It is inefficient to take slices of the list. This kills the benefit of binary search. Instead, pass the start and end indices of the intended sublist as arguments without actually slicing the list, and make sure the function only looks at the part of the list between those two indices.
- The `try...except` block seems to suggest you think that taking a slice can trigger an index error. It can't. However, there will be such an exception deeper in the recursion tree, when the list is empty. It would be better to have a base case test (to detect the current range is empty).